Dynamic URL pattern for CategoryPage in SAP Spartacus 4.x
I'm working in Spartacus and I want to add dynamic params in CategoryPage URL.
Say my current categoryPage URL looks like: http://server.com/categories/ballpens which I want to change to http://server.com/categories/stationary/office/pens/ballpens.
My current routing code snippet:
@NgModule({
  declarations: ...,
  imports: [ ConfigModule.withConfig({
...,routing: {
            routes: {
              category: { paths: ['categories/:categoryCode'] },
            }
          }
 } as CmsConfig)})

and I am expecting something like below to work(which is incorrect solution for reference):
@NgModule({
  declarations: ...,
  imports: [ ConfigModule.withConfig({
...,routing: {
            routes: {
              category: { paths: ['categories/**/:categoryCode'] },
            }
          }
 } as CmsConfig)})

Can anyone please assist me to resolve this?
Any input would be appreciated.

paths: ['categories/:param1/:param2/:param3/:categoryCode']

Thanks @moh for your input. We need to support n level of categories in URL. The url can have only param1 and then categoryCode or upto param10 and then categoryCode.
